# How to populate model properties when one of the properties is computed from another two obtained through an API call?

Tags: swift, swiftui, mvvm, geocoding

**[Solved]**

I was not treating `reverseGeocode` as an asynchronous function, leading to timing issues and data not populating correctly. Using `async await` solved the issue.

**Solution:**

```swift
func getCurrentWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async throws -> WeatherReport? {
        do {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&exclude=current,minutely,hourly, alerts&appid=19054ace743dfdfd9&units=imperial") else { throw NetworkError.badURL}
            
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkError.badResponse }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else { throw NetworkError.badStatus }
            
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherReport.self, from: data)
            let decodedDataWithCity = try await decodedData.reverseGeocode()
            return decodedDataWithCity
            
        } catch NetworkError.badURL {
            print("Error creating URL")
        } catch NetworkError.badResponse {
            print("Didn't get a valid response")
        } catch NetworkError.badStatus {
            print("Didn't get a 2xx status code from response")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred downloading the data")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

```swift
func reverseGeocode() async throws -> WeatherReport? {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        var report: WeatherReport?
        
        do {
            let placemarks = try await geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location)
            let placemark = placemarks.first
            report = WeatherReport(lat: lat, lon: lon, city: placemark?.locality, timezone: timezone, timezoneOffset: timezoneOffset, daily: daily)
        } catch {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
        
        return report
    }
```

---

```swift
func getCurrentWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async throws -> WeatherReport? {
        do {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&exclude=current,minutely,hourly, alerts&appid=19054ace749133743dfdfd9&units=imperial") else { throw NetworkError.badURL}
            
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkError.badResponse }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else { throw NetworkError.badStatus }
            
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherReport.self, from: data)
            let decodedDataWithCity = decodedData.reverseGeocode(latitude: decodedData.lat, longitude: decodedData.lon)
            return decodedDataWithCity
            
        } catch NetworkError.badURL {
            print("Error creating URL")
        } catch NetworkError.badResponse {
            print("Didn't get a valid response")
        } catch NetworkError.badStatus {
            print("Didn't get a 2xx status code from response")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred downloading the data")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

---

**[Original Post]**

I'm building a simple weather app that displays:

- User's city name (having trouble with this part)
- Current temp
- Daily min/max temp
- Wind speed
- Humidity

The [OpenWeatherMap API](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3) provides data for everything **except** city name, and I am having trouble figuring out the logic flow to obtain it.

---

**My current (failed) approach is:**

1. Create a model called `WeatherReport` containing all properties of a weather report.

```swift
struct WeatherReport: Codable {
    var lat, lon: Double
    var city: String?
    let timezone: String
    let timezoneOffset: Int
    let daily: [Daily]
```

- I've added `city` here as optional because the API called to populate these properties will not return a city name.
- `city` a computed property that's determined through reverse geocoding (provide latitude, longitude and return location name).

---

2. Add .task to download data from API and decode into model (this is working).

```swift
func getCurrentWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async throws -> WeatherReport? {
        do {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&exclude=current,minutely,hourly, alerts&appid=19054ace7493dfdfd9&units=imperial") else { throw NetworkError.badURL}
            
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkError.badResponse }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else { throw NetworkError.badStatus }
            
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherReport.self, from: data)
            return decodedData
            
        } catch NetworkError.badURL {
            print("Error creating URL")
        } catch NetworkError.badResponse {
            print("Didn't get a valid response")
        } catch NetworkError.badStatus {
            print("Didn't get a 2xx status code from response")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred downloading the data")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

---

**(Here's where I'm having all the trouble)**

3. Populate the `city` property now that we have lat/lon data available.

---

*Attempt #1*

- Create `reverseGeocode` function that takes latitute/longitude (CLLocationDegrees) and returns a city name (String).
- Use `didSet` property observer on lat/lon properties to call `reverseGeocode` function to compute `city`

Failed because `'var' declarations with multiple variables cannot have explicit getters/setters`

```swift
var lat, lon: Double {
        didSet {
            self.city = reverseGeocode(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
        }
    }
```

```swift
func reverseGeocode(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) -> String {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        var cityName: String
        
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
            print("in geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation function")
            // ensure no error
            guard error == nil else { return }
            
            // ensure there are placemarks
            if let placemarks = placemarks,
               let placemark = placemarks.first {
                cityName = placemark.locality ?? "Current location"
            }
        }
        
        return cityName
    }
```

---

*Attempt #2*

- Change the `reverseGeocode` method to return a `WeatherReport` rather than a `String`
- Within the original API call, once a `WeatherReport` (excluding city name) has been successfully decoded - we call `reverseGeocode` method to generate a new `WeatherReport` that does include city name.

Failed because it's hung up on the async task of obtaining the `WeatherReport` to generate the view. Originally thought the `reverseGeocode` method wasn't working, but added some print statements inside it that confirms it is.

The view is stuck on the loading spinner while waiting for the `WeatherReport` to come in.

```swift
@EnvironmentObject private var locationManager: LocationManager
private let weatherManager = WeatherManager()
@State var weatherReport: WeatherReport?

var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // if location exists...
            if let location = locationManager.location {
                // ..and weather report exists
                if let weatherReport = weatherReport {
                    // show WeatherView
                    WeatherView(weatherReport: weatherReport)
                } else {
                    // show loading spinner
                    LoadingView()
                        .task {
                            do {
                                // obtain weather report
                                weatherReport = try await weatherManager.getCurrentWeather(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)
                            } catch {
                                print("Unable to get weather info - Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                            }
                        }
                }
```

```swift
func getCurrentWeather(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) async throws -> WeatherReport? {
        do {
            guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/3.0/onecall?lat=\(latitude)&lon=\(longitude)&exclude=current,minutely,hourly, alerts&appid=19054ace749743dfdfd9&units=imperial") else { throw NetworkError.badURL}
            
            let (data, response) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            
            guard let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else { throw NetworkError.badResponse }
            guard response.statusCode >= 200 && response.statusCode < 300 else { throw NetworkError.badStatus }
            
            let decodedData = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherReport.self, from: data)
            let decodedDataWithCity = decodedData.reverseGeocode(latitude: decodedData.lat, longitude: decodedData.lon)
            return decodedDataWithCity
            
        } catch NetworkError.badURL {
            print("Error creating URL")
        } catch NetworkError.badResponse {
            print("Didn't get a valid response")
        } catch NetworkError.badStatus {
            print("Didn't get a 2xx status code from response")
        } catch {
            print("An error occurred downloading the data")
        }
        
        return nil
    }
```

```swift
func reverseGeocode(latitude: CLLocationDegrees, longitude: CLLocationDegrees) -> WeatherReport {
        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()
        let location = CLLocation(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        var report: WeatherReport
        
        geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(location) { placemarks, error in
            print("in geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation function")
            // ensure no error
            guard error == nil else { return }
            
            // ensure there are placemarks
            if let placemarks = placemarks,
               let placemark = placemarks.first {
                report = WeatherReport(lat: lat, lon: lon, city: placemark.locality, timezone: timezone, timezoneOffset: timezoneOffset, daily: daily)
                print("report: \(report)")
            }
        }
        
        return report
    }
```

---

For additional context here's the view I'm trying to build. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `CityView`, e.g.

```
struct CityView: View {
    @Environment(\.myGeocoder) var myGeocoder
    let lat, lon: Double
    @State var city: City?

    var body: some View {
        Text(city.name ?? "Loading...")
        .task(id: [lat, lon]) {
            do {
                city = try await myGeocoder.reverseGeocode(latitude: lat, longitude: lon)
            }
            catch {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
}
```